# Meaning and usage of "Gentlebeing"

Tags: meaning

I wonder what *gentlebeing* means and how it is used, especially when compared to similar phrases like *Ladies and gentlemen!*

I saw *Gentlebeings!* being used at the beginning of an email. Is it a formal or informal word, and does it have any sarcastic or humorous connotation to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not an accepted word (at least not yet), but an attempt (semi-humorous, at a guess), to find an appropriate salutation for a group of people, some of whom may object to "Ladies and Gentlemen".  People have been attempting this for years, without noticeable success: "Gentlebeings", though harmless, has too much of a science-fiction flavour to catch on generally, I would say.

Comment: Thanks! Why would some object to "Ladies and Gentlemen"?

Comment: Some women object to being called "Ladies", perhaps because of the stereotype of "ladylike behaviour".  Others object to unnecessary distinctions in language between men and women; for example it has become common to use "an actor" as a general term instead of calling about half of them "an actress".

Comment: Others object to the notion of a [gender binary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_binary).

Comment: But this word is a step beyond mere gender. If we wanted a word that included males and females, it would be something like "[gentlefolk](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gentlefolk?q=gentlefolk)". "Gentlebeings" is deliberately designed to include not only humans, but representatives of any and all non-human species who may be present. All human beings, and all alien beings: gentlebeings all.

Answer (score 1):

SF flavour is right, it's been used by Anne McCaffrey (in one of the *Brain Ships* novels), Larry Niven (*Fallen Angels*), Alan Dean Foster (Flinx books), Gordon Dickson (*Hokas Pokas*), Keith Laumer (*Odyssey*), Doohan & Stirling (*The Privateer*), John Ringo (*There Will be Dragons*) and Poul Anderson (*Flandry*) to name but a few.

I imagine it's connected with Shakespeare's "Gentles" (*Henry IV & V*, *A Midsummmer Night's Dream*, *Taming of the Shrew*) which might be more acceptable to non-fen. ["Fen" is the plural of fan in the speech of SF aficionados.]

Comment: helpful information on the SF usage. But can you source the connection with Shakespeare or is that just your conjecture?

Comment: Isn't 'fan/fen' also sexist then? What about 'wofan/wofen'?  [pronounced wufan/wiffin]

Answer (score 0):

"Gentlebeings" is an informal word which is widely used in science fiction works. It is deliberately designed to include not only humans (of both genders), but representatives of any and all non-human species who may be present. All human beings, and all alien beings: gentlebeings all.